# In a linked list delete function, is it necessary to use free to delete a node?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I saw [this](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/) node delete function and compared it to my book's. It's (almost) totally different, I would guess the latter is useful for learning matters...? but then I can't understand why free is even used if all it takes is to move the pointer forward. Maybe I'm missing something.

For reference, here's my book's delete node function:

```
char delete(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value){
  if(value == (*sPtr)->data){
    ListNodePtr tempPtr = *sPtr; 
    *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr; 
    free(tempPtr); 
    return value;
  }
  else{
    ListNodePtr previousPtr = *sPtr;
    ListNodePtr currentPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;

  while(currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value){
    previousPtr = currentPtr; 
    currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
  }
  
    if(currentPtr != NULL){
      ListNodePtr tempPtr = currentPtr;
      previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
      free(tempPtr);
      return value;
    }
  }

  return '\0';
}
```

I also tried completely removing both the temp variable and the free call and the function still (apparently) works, as in the print function doesn't print the "deleted" value.

Been checking out other sources on linked lists and many of those show usage of the free function, odd.

Comment: Most probably because you are allocating the memory using `malloc` or `calloc`. Such memories need to be freed or the program will have memory leaks.

Comment: The Linus quote is mostly about `using a pointer-to-pointer to avoid complexity caused by special cases`. The code from the book fails to do so. [instead, it hides a pointer behind a `typedef`]

Answer (score 2):

Linus describes lists as used in the Linux kernel there. And the one interesting thing is that those are intrusive lists, meaning the list-management-code is *not* responsible for freeing nodes, as the list doesn't *own* them.

Also, the code on that site is not a complete function for deleting nodes, but only the lines for unlinking them.

Your own list will probably be an owning list though, using `malloc()`-ed memory, right?

Comment: Thanks, that's closer to what I wanted to know. It seemed odd to me that his of all codes would be this wrong and also end up on an article.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the code is very and very bad. Firstly there are duplicate code. And secondly the function is made too complicated.

It can be written much simpler. For example

```
char delete( ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value )
{
    while ( *sPtr != NULL && ( *sPtr )->data != value )
    {
        sPtr = &( *sPtr )->nextPtr;
    }

    char result = *sPtr == NULL ? '\0' : value;

    if ( *sPtr != NULL )
    {
        ListNodePtr tempPtr = *sPtr;
        *sPtr = ( *sPtr )->nextPtr;
        free( tempPtr );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Also it is a bad idea to use a typedef for pointers as in your program where `ListNodePtr` is evidently is such a typedef. For example this type specifier

```
const ListNodePtr
```

does not mean that data pointed to by a pointer of the type `ListNodePtr` is a constant data and may not be changed. It means that the pointer itself is constant.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int * IntPtr;

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    const IntPtr p = &x;

    *p = 20;

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
x = 20
```

As for your question

> In a linked list delete function, is it necessary to use free to
>   delete a node?

then the reference to the deleted node will be lost after exiting the function and if the node will not be deleted there will be a memory leak provided that the node was allocated dynamically.

Comment: So stuff like those currentPtr and previousPtr variables is actually not suggested? I'm honestly really confused because I thought it was good practice to use them like that, but I'm reading so many conflicting opinions about it.

Comment: @Impasse Using currentPtr and previousPtr is a Java style where there is no pointers. In C or C++ this can be written more more simpler without introducing intermediate variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use free then you are causing memory leak. If you move your pointer without freeing the memory then it will cause memory leak.